# CAPM-model - necessary conditions for BETA to be a parameter in the conditional expectation

Tags: normal-distribution

CAPM-model - necessary conditions for BETA to be a parameter in the conditional expectation between the real return on the asset and the stock market return.

Okay, trying to be more explicit:
Let $\mu_{at}$ denote the total required rate of return on an asset in period $t$. The capital pricing model (CAPM) states that: 
$\mu _{at}=r_t+\phi _t \sigma _a \rho _{am}$
where $r_t$ is a riskless interest rate in time period $t$. $\phi_t$ is an aggregated market parameter. $\sigma_a$ and $\rho_{am}$ are parameters if the joint probability density function $f(r_{at},r_{mt})$ of the return on an individual asset ($r_{at})$ and the stock market return ($r_{mt})$. $\sigma_a$ is the standard deviation of the real return on the asset, and $\rho_{am}$ is the correlation between $r_{at}, r_{mt}$. The rest is now explained below (I do not know if there's more information you need? I don't have more information.)

I have the model $\mu _{at}=r_t+\phi _t \sigma _a \rho _{am}$. And as you probably know, this can be rewritten such that:

$\mu_{at}=r_t+(E(r_{mt})-r_t){\sigma_{am}}/{\sigma_m^2}$ in the case where $\phi_t=({E(r_{mt})-r_t})/{\sigma_m}$

Now let $\beta_a^{CAPM} \equiv {\sigma_{am}}/{\sigma_m^2}$

What I am supposed to find out is this: Under which sufficient assumption(s) is $\beta_a^{CAPM}$ a parameter in the conditional expectation function $E(r_{at}|r_{mt})$? Explain.

I know this has to do with the normal distribution and the pdf of a bivariate normal distribution, but I'm not sure I catch all the points, so if you guys know the drill, I would be delighted.

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more explicit about what the context of this question is. Something something economics?

Comment: I have tried to be more explicit now.